# Прочесть журнал безопасности Windows без прав администратора

Tags: c#, windows, безопасность

Пишу приложение для того чтобы выводить журналы Windows в нужном мне виде. Ради пробы написал консольную прогу, которая просто извлекает все записи из всех журналов. Вот ее код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
        foreach(var log in logs)
        {
            try
            {
                var collection = log.Entries;
                foreach (EventLogEntry entry in collection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", entry.TimeGenerated, entry.Source, entry.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(log.LogDisplayName);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Все работает здорово, пока цикл не добирается до журнала "Безопасность". Вылетает исключение "Запрошенный доступ к реестру защищен". Решается это запуском с правами администратора. Проблема в том, что мне нельзя запускать приложение с правами администратора. Есть ли какое-то обходное решение?

Comment: Игнорировать журнал "Безопасность"?

Comment: @ГеннадийП , не прокатит. Мне нужны все журналы.

Comment: Почему нельзя запускать приложение с правами администратора?

Comment: Требование заказчика.

Comment: Нет доступа к админской учетке?

Comment: Доступ есть. Но дать приложению права админа нельзя. Работать оно будет в жестко ограниченной в правах учетке.

Comment: 1) Запускать из приложения процесс с правами администратора, но пострадает безопасность, т.к. учетные данные будут храниться в приложении. 2) Создать сервис с нужными правами, с которым и общаться из приложения.

Comment: Добавьте юзера в BUILT IN\Event Log Readers

Comment: Привет, скажи пожалуйста, а как сделать так чтобы, я смог выводить только опеределенные Логи, те которые мне нужно, допустим сработал лог , и шарп его отфильтровал и отправил мне на консоль.

Comment: @ДмитрийАгаев что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите, что вам нужны определенные логи? Если нужно сканировать только специфический журнал, то свойство `Source` в помощь. Если вам нужна подписка на срабатывание определенного события, то лучшим вариантом, который пришел в голову, мне кажется периодическое сканирование журнала на нужные события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге нашел решение в связке Служба Windows-Приложение. Служба считывает по запросу события и передает их в приложение, используя `NamedPipes`.
Приведу здесь некоторые методы, так сказать для будущего.

Класс взаимодействия для службы:

```
public class PipeFunctions
{
    static bool[] clientsArray = new bool[] { false, false, false };
    CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();


    public static void StartExchange()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!clientsArray[i])
            {
                StartPipeServerAsync();
                clientsArray[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static async void StartPipeServerAsync()
    {
        var ps = new PipeSecurity();

        // себе разрешаем все
        ps.AddAccessRule(
            new PipeAccessRule(
                WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner,
                    PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        // остальным только чтение/запись в пайп
        ps.AddAccessRule(
            new PipeAccessRule(
                new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
                    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));

        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("EventServerPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 3, PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
            PipeOptions.None,0,0,ps);
        // Ожидание подключения клиента
        await pipeServer.WaitForConnectionAsync();
        try
        {

            StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);
            // Подтверждение
            int counter = 0;
            ss.WriteString("I am the one true server!");
            while (true)
            {
                string dataString = ss.ReadString();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataString))
                {
                    if (dataString != "Client disconnected!")
                    {
                        // Непосредственно получение данных о системных событиях
                        // и формирование сообщения для передачи
                        var logs = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
                        foreach (var log in logs)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var collection = log.Entries;
                                foreach (EventLogEntry entry in collection)
                                {
                                    ss.WriteString(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4} - {5} - {6} - {7} - {8}",
                                        log.LogDisplayName, entry.EntryType, entry.Index, entry.MachineName, entry.Message, entry.Source,
                                        entry.TimeGenerated, entry.TimeWritten, entry.UserName));
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Выводим ошибочку в файл не прерывая передачи
                                File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), "AdminServiceErrors.txt"), new string[] { ex.Message });
                            }
                        }
                        // Сообщаем о том, что закончили передачу
                        ss.WriteString("Finish");
                        // Выводим в файл количество переданных сообщений (исключительно для проверки)
                        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), "AdminServiceResult.txt"), new string[] { string.Format("Отправлено {0} сообщений",counter) });
                    }
                    else
                        break;

                }

                else break;
            }

        }
        // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
        // or disconnected.
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        pipeServer.Close();
        for (int i = 0; i < clientsArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (clientsArray[i])
            {
                clientsArray[i] = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        StartExchange();
    }
}
```

Здесь служба постоянно ожидает подключения до трех клиентов и каждому из подключившихся выдает все сообщения из журналов Windows в специальном (нужном мне) формате.

В свою очередь клиент выглядит как-то так:

```
class Program
{
    static int counter = 0;
    static string data = "";
    public static List<HMIEventGroup> HMIEventGroups { get; set; } = new List<HMIEventGroup>();
    public static bool CollectionIsBusy { get; set; } = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PipeClientConnectAsync();
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static async void PipeClientConnectAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
                                   new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "EventServerPipe",
                                       PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None, TokenImpersonationLevel.Anonymous);

            await pipeClient.ConnectAsync();
            StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeClient);
            if (ss.ReadString() == "I am the one true server!")
            {
                ss.WriteString("Connected");
                string temp = "";
                Console.WriteLine("Начали получать данные");
                while(true)
                {                        
                    temp = ss.ReadString();
                    if(temp!="Finish")
                    {
                        HMIEvent.ParseAsync(temp);
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server could not be verified.");
            }
            pipeClient.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Получено {0} сообщений", counter);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

После получения каждого сообщения вызывается асинхронный метод `HMIEvent.ParseAsync()`, который разбирает строку и превращает ее в экземпляр нужного мне класса.
На передачу ~32000 сообщений уходит ~10 секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Зарегистрируйте свое приложение как службу от имени системы.

Comment: Если честно, впервые слышу о подобном. Требует ли это каких-то манипуляций с кодом? Или просто достаточно воспользоваться installutil?

Comment: Погуглите на тему sc, создание сервиса / службы в windows.  Материала полным полно