# Статическая библитека на C#

Tags: c#, dll, windows-service

Потребовалось мне создать службу Windows и десктопное приложение. Обе этих программы, в идеале, должны работать с одной и той же коллекцией пользовательского типа данных, чтобы одновременно и быстро реагировать на любые изменения в этой коллекции. Возможен, конечно, вариант с использованием каког-либо конфигурационного файла, об изменениях в котором десктопное приложение сообщит службе с помощью команды, но этот вариант не очень удобен. На данный момент оба приложения используют одну и ту же библиотеку (dll), в которой используемая коллекция и находится, но каждая из прог использует свой экземпляр и поэтому служба не видит, какие изменения были внесены в коллецию десктопным приложением и наоборот. Отсюда вопрос: можно ли создать "Статическую" библиотеку на c# либо решить проблему передачи данных другим способом?

UPD:

Решение проблемы нашел. Использовал NamedPipes. Подробно об этом способе написал [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937992/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-windows-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Другим способом. Вам нужно межпроцессное (crossprocess) взаимодействие прог, например, через бд, через шину сообщений (типа msmq), через именованные каналы (named pipes), ну или каким другим способам.

Comment: использование WCF может решить мою проблему?

Comment: с Wcf тоже можно изобрести свой велосипед. смотрите в сторону WCF Long Polling. смысл которого заключается в подвешивании запроса на сервере (вашем сервисе, например) и возврате результата в случае срабатывания тригера - изменения коллекции. Конечно после каждого возврата должен быть сделан новый запрос-ожидание

Comment: Я бы смотрел в первую очередь в сторону NamedPipe. Если хочется WCF - можете использовать. Опять же, берите привязку NetNamedPipeBinding.

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека не хранит вашу коллекцию, она хранится в памяти, по этому никакая "статичная" библиотека не поможет вам решить вашу проблему. По сути вы хотите выделить память для доступа из обоих приложений. В .Net приложениях сделать это невозможно, по тому что каждый апп запускается в своем домене.

По этому для решения проблемы вам нужен некий посредник, к которому ваши приложения будут обращаться за пользовательскими данными.
Способы решения зависят от объемов данных, способа их изменения и тп.

Если речь идет о обмене небольшого объема данных, то можно применить такую технику как Memory Mapped Files, изменения можно определять по блокировке\разблокировке доступа.

Если объем данных значительный, то лучше будет воспользоваться базой данных и реализовать подписку на изменения.

Так же можно воспользоваться шиной данных, например msmq.